# Google play integrity API - Invalid app check token error after adding app to Firebase project

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-app-check, google-play-integrity-api

I am trying to implement `firebase app check` in my android app using `Play-Integrity API`. I have added both my **SHA-1** & **SHA-256** fingerprints in my firebase app (acquired from `Google play console` and `Android studio gradle signing report` both) into my firebase app.

I have added this code inside all my activities in my app, before using any other `Firebase SDKs`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
    FirebaseAppCheck firebaseAppCheck = FirebaseAppCheck.getInstance();
    firebaseAppCheck.installAppCheckProviderFactory(PlayIntegrityAppCheckProviderFactory.getInstance());
}
```

---

Now no matter how many times I run my app, I keep getting the error in my console:

```
pc_0 - Detected invalid AppCheck token. Reconnecting (2 attempts remaining)
pc_0 - Detected invalid AppCheck token. Reconnecting (1 attempts remaining)
pc_0 - Detected invalid AppCheck token. Reconnecting (0 attempts remaining)

pc_0 - Firebase Database connection was forcefully killed by the server. Will not attempt reconnect. Reason: Invalid appcheck token
```

I have followed all the steps exactly as mentioned in [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/android/play-integrity-provider) page. My app is already uploaded in **Google play store**, and **Google Play Integrity API** is already enabled in `Google cloud console`. What more do I need to do? Please help me.

Comment: Consider filing an issue via https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues with more details (e.g. package name)

Comment: _Firebaser here._

Agree with Abzal's response -- please file an issue at the above link, and include details you are comfortable sharing. You can also file a support ticket directly with [Firebase Support](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/contact) without publicizing those details.

Answer (score 0):

if you are under debug mode you should add debug token to your appcheck :

**Appcheck** -- > **Application** -- > **Manage debug token**

add this line to your gradle :

```
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appcheck-debug:16.1.2'
```

And then instantiate your appcheck this way :

```
   FirebaseApp.initializeApp(getApplicationContext());
   FirebaseAppCheck firebaseAppCheck = FirebaseAppCheck.getInstance();
   firebaseAppCheck.installAppCheckProviderFactory(
            DebugAppCheckProviderFactory.getInstance());
```

After that , lunch your application , in your logcat , look for this :

```
D DebugAppCheckProvider: Enter this debug secret into the allow list in
the Firebase Console for your project: 123a4567-b89c-12d3-e456-789012345678
```

So you need to add this token `123a4567-b89c-12d3-e456-789012345678` in your Appcheck debug token .

this should work for you !